# Elif syntax error with nested if conditions

Tags: python, if-statement

The interpreter gives me a syntax error when it reaches elif in the code below. Why?

```
while walls:
    rand_wall = walls[int(random.random()*len(walls))-1]
    if rand_wall[1] != 0 and rand_wall[1] != mazeheight-1:
        if maze[rand_wall[0][rand_wall[1]-1] == "u" and maze[rand_wall[0][rand_wall[1]+1] == "c":
            print("no")
        elif maze[rand_wall[0][rand_wall[1]-1] == "c" and maze[rand_wall[0][rand_wall[1]+1] == "u":
            print("no")
```

If the first condition is true, I want to check a second condition and its mirror condition and run some code (replaced with print("no") for debugging) if either condition is true.

Comment: _The interpreter gives me a syntax error_ Please [edit] and add the full stack trace.

Comment: you are missing some closing brackets in your statements

Comment: `rand_wall` gets indexed in the same way several times; I would use some temporary variables to clean this up.

Comment: Also, `rand_wall = random.choice(walls)` would be much simpler.

Comment: The less syntax you have, the fewer places a syntax error can occur.

Comment: Is `maze` a nested list? You currently have the equivalent of `maze[xy]` instead of `maze[x][y]` that I think you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would clean this up to avoid the chance of syntax error. I'm assuming, for example, that

```
maze[rand_wall[0][rand_wall[1]-1]
```

should be

```
maze[rand_wall[0]][rand_wall[1]-1] 
                 ^
                 add missing ]
```

---

```
while walls:
    x, y = random.choice(walls)
    if y != 0 and y != mazeheight-1:
        row = maze[x]
        if row[y-1] == "u" and row[y+1] == "c":
            print("no")
        elif row[y-1] == "c" and row[y+1] == "u":
            print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some closing brackets missing.

```
while walls:
    rand_wall = walls[int(random.random()*len(walls))-1]
    if rand_wall[1] != 0 and rand_wall[1] != mazeheight-1:
        if maze[rand_wall[0][rand_wall[1]-1] == "u" and maze[rand_wall[0][rand_wall[1]+1]]] == "c": # added two closing brackets before the == sign.
            print("no")
        elif maze[rand_wall[0][rand_wall[1]-1] == "c" and maze[rand_wall[0][rand_wall[1]+1]]] == "u": # same as before
            print("no")
```

It should run now, but I don't know the expected behavior. Next time try to post the full stack trace.

Comment: I think  something along the lines of this makes more sense `if maze[rand_wall[0]][rand_wall[1]-1] == "u" and maze[rand_wall[0]][rand_wall[1]+1] == "c":`